# Derivative of Parameterized Polar Coordinates

Tags: vector-analysis

Given that the position of a particle as a function of time $t$ in polar coordinates is given by

$s(t) = r(t)\angle\phi(t)$

in which $r(t) = e^{-t}$ is the modulus of position and $\phi(t) = t$ is the angle, how do I find the velocity of the particle $v(t) = s'(t)$? I mean, how do I calculate the derivative of a parameterized vector in polar coordinates?

I tried to transform $s(t)$ to rectangular coordinates, i.e.:

$s(t) = (r(t)\cos[\phi(t)] , r(t)\sin[\phi(t)]) = (e^{-t}\cos(t), e^{-t}\sin(t))$

and then taking the derivative of this and the modulus results in:

$|v(t)|^2 = 2e^{-2t}\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,$(i)

But this is not the same as taking the direct derivative of the modulus of $s(t)$ which is:

$r'(t) = \dfrac{d}{dt}e^{-t} = -e^{-t}$

which squared is:

$(r'(t))^2 = e^{-2t}\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,$                     (2)

but (1) $\neq$ (2). Where is my error?

Answer (score 0):

You have
$$s(t) = r(t) (\cos\phi(t), \sin\phi(t))$$

Then
$$s'(t) = r'(t) (\cos\phi(t), \sin\phi(t)) + r(t) \phi'(t) (-\sin\phi(t), \cos\phi(t))$$
so
$$|s'(t)|^2 = s'(t) \cdot s'(t) = r'(t)^2 + r(t)^2 \phi'(t)^2$$
since
$$(\cos\phi(t), \sin\phi(t)) \cdot (-\sin\phi(t), \cos\phi(t)) = 0$$

What you forget is thus the term $r(t)^2 \phi'(t)^2$.

Comment: But if you replace $r(t)$ and $\phi(t)$ by the functions I gave in the question, the result will be exactly what I obtained, i.e. $|s'(t)|^2 = |v(t)|^2= 2e^{-2t}$.

Comment: Yes, $|s'(t)|^2 = 2 e^{-2t}$. In your case $r'(t)^2 = e^{-2t}$ and $r(t)^2 \phi'(t)^2 = e^{-2t}$, so $r'(t)^2 + r(t)^2 \phi'(t)^2 = 2 e^{-2t}$. But $|s'(t)|^2 \neq r'(t)^2$ unless $r=0$ or $\phi'(t)=0$.